# .htaccess condition for admin area

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need to write condition for non admin area.
Please, help me with syntax.

```
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|png)$">
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /watermark/_watermark.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L,QSA]
</FilesMatch>
```

for example - if url has no **/admin/** substring - it should be true for script executing.

Thanks,

Comment: You should be watermarking on upload and serve that static file to save on server load.

Comment: Is watermarking on upload better practice and less for server resources?

Comment: Correct. That way you only process the image once, not on every single request.

Comment: But if i have tinyMce editor, in what way i need to process image? Only customizations for tinemce or something else?

Comment: Can't help you with that, never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use that as your pattern for `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !(^|/)admin/ /watermark/_watermark.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L,QSA]
```